# multiple iframes on page - only IE changes the other frame properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, firefox

I have multiple iframe items on a page (vb.net based application), in particular, one is a frame that holds links that generate the details frame. Currently the javascript is working for IE but when used in any other browser it does not work correctly. Here is the line that is causing this error

```
window.parent.detailFrame.location.href = form + "?cat=" + cat + "&par=" + par + "&HighlightID=" + HighlightID;
```

I can tell this line is incorrect in firefox because when placing alerts in the function after this line, they do not fire, but they do in IE. can anyone see what needs to be done for this to work in both firefox and IE? Thank you.

edit:

i am able to use items like 
    window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').location 
or window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').href but not like window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').location.href - when using just .location or .href the iframe doesnt refresh to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

was able to redo using .src, not location.href

Answer (score -1):

I think all you need to do is set the location, not the location's href:

```
window.parent.detailFrame.location = form + "?cat=" + cat + "&par=" + par + "&HighlightID=" + HighlightID;
```

Comment: Erm... no. Changing the location is a haxy way of changing its href.

Comment: i am able to use items like window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').location or window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').href but not like window.parent.getElementById('detailFrame').location.href - when using just .location or .href the iframe doesnt refresh to the new page.